# How to left align all LI links, but right adjust pictures within the same LI link?

Tags: css, alignment

I've got the following code that is being used in a Drop-down menu:

```css
.menu-label {
    font-size: 0;
}

.menu-label.coming-soon:before {
    background: url(lb-coming-soon1.png);
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Soap Company</a><span class="menu-label coming-soon"></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Apparel <span class="menu-label coming-soon"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is have the Menu display the text link left align, and the related "Coming Soon" picture right aligned.

right now, it looks a disjointed. I'm not sure how/what to change in the css to make the alignment work as desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a few method according to which structure and which browsers you want to support.

examples :

```css
/* reset and basic makup */
ul {
  padding:2em;
  }
li {
  background:lightgray;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 3px;
}
a {
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:left;
  color:green
  }

.menu-label.coming-soon:before {/* include image*/
  display: inline-block;
  content: url(http://dummyimage.com/40x20/abc/f00&text=soon);
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* float first element and align right text */
li.float {
  text-align: right;
}
a.float {
  float: left;
}
/* end float */

    /*=== */

/* flex & justify-content */

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
/* end flex */

    /*=== */

/* text-align */

.justify, .justifyli{
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height:0em;
}
[class^="justify"]:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 99%;
}
/* end  text-align */
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="float">
    <a href="#" class="float">float a</a>
    <span class="menu-label coming-soon"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="flex">
    <a href="#" >flex li</a>
    <span class="menu-label coming-soon"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="flex">flex a
      <span class="menu-label coming-soon"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="buggy, text needs to be wrapped" class="justify">justify  a
      <span class="menu-label coming-soon"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="justifyli">
    <a href="#">justify  li</a>
    <span class="menu-label coming-soon"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox and `justify-content` to separate the elements.

`li { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }`

And looks like you have an HTML discrepancy between the list items. Change the 2nd one to

`<li><a href="#">Apparel</a> <span class="menu-label coming-soon"></span></li>`